# Is there a vegan alternative to Ovaltine?

Tags: veganism, substitutes

I'm looking for something that shares Ovaltine's texture and taste, but that's vegan -- [milk](https://www.ingredientsarc.com/product/ovaltine-original/) is the only bit that makes it not vegan, it looks like.

Given the texture and the taste are two really important bits, I'm not looking for something like just mixing ["cocoa, hot water and soy milk."](https://www.veggieboards.com/forum/60-vegan-support-forum/68403-vegan-alternative-ovaltine.html)

Does anyone know of any alternative that's appropriate?

Answer (score 11):

I did a bit more research, and found a few "homemade Ovaltine" recipes, such as [this one](https://vegetariangastronomy.com/home-made-ovaltine-contains-dairy-contains-gluten/) — none of which are vegan. That being said, they all appear to have the same basic ingredients:

- Barley malt powder
- Milk powder
- Cocoa powder (if we're going for a chocolate-y version, which is what I'm looking for)

So if I replace the milk powder with a powdered milk substitute — like soy milk powder — I should be good to go! *:fingers_crossed:*

Note that I haven't actually tried this yet, so I'm not sure if I'll be able to match Ovaltine's flavor and texture... but I'll update this answer once I give it a try :)

Comment: I won't accept this answer because I haven't tried it yet, and because I don't want to discourage others who may have store-bought (or other) alternatives they know of from answering :)

Comment: Did you ever remember to try this?  How did it turn out?

Answer (score 6):

Apparently [Horlicks has launched a vegan version in Asda](https://www.somersetlive.co.uk/whats-on/food-drink/vegan-horlicks-being-sold-asda-4578648).

Answer (score 4):

I’m assuming you live in the US and I’m surprised to hear it isn’t vegan already. The ones they sell in Brazil don’t contain milk powder and they’ve recently removed the vitamin D (from animal sources) it previously contained, so now it’s “completely vegan.”

I only used quotation marks because ABF sells their products in some places that actually require animal testing, and I don’t know if that might bother you or not.

Comment: What?! This is amazing. Ovaltine is so unvegan in India and the UK. I read Brazil has the second biggest Ovaltine factory. Good to know they're making it vegan (I checked ingredients on amazon.com.br) :)

Comment: @Zanna Ovaltine is INSANELY popular in Brazil, the "crunchy" version in particular - which apparently was a problem in the production line. If you can get your hands on it, I highly recommend